# Monthly mean raster output seem to get multiplied automatically by 10000 in code

Tags: raster, r, mean

I have 519 .tiff files (3 files per month (e.g. 20060103.tif, 20060113.tif, 20060124.tif, 20070203.tif. 20070213.tif, 20070224.tif...etc). I am calculating monthly mean using following code in R. But the problem is that the cell values of tiff files is in the range 0-1 but the final output of the code has cell values in the range 0-10000. I also checked it manually. For example, a cell whose monthly mean output should be 0.1265 has monthly mean as 1265. I don't understand that in which step, the values are getting multiplied by 10000 and how? I do not want these values to get multiplied by 10000. I want only mean. What is wrong?

```
setwd("D:/Data")
library(raster)
rast <- list.files(path="D:/Data/",pattern='.*tif',full.names=TRUE)
rast[1:519]
s <- stack(rast)
names(s)[1:519]
grp = substr(names(s),2,7)        
grp[1:519]
alb_mean <- stackApply(s, grp, mean)
names(alb_mean)[1:519]
for(n in names(alb_mean)){writeRaster(alb_mean[[n]], paste0(n,".tif"))}
list.files(path=".",pattern=".tif")
```

The output of

```
raster::raster(rast[6]) |> raster::values() |> summary()

 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
 3132    4020    4449    4644    5134    7657     290
```

Comment: are you sure the rasters are really in the range 0-1? They might scaled ints instead of floating point.

Comment: You can check if the values are scaled from the metadata of the TIFF. Gdalinfo for example shows the metadata.

Comment: What is the output of `raster::raster(rast[1]) |> raster::values() |> summary()`?

Comment: @dimfalk Pls check the updated portion.

Comment: Yes the input rasters are in the range of 0-1. And the output raster is in the range 0-10000. I checked the histograms of both the data.

Comment: Does `rast[1]` contain NA values only by chance? Maybe choose some layer containing actual values?

Comment: However, please have a look at [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in general. And regarding your specific question, it might be best if you provide the first three files you're having problems with to have sth for testing.

Comment: rast[1] is having NA values by chance. I have added output for rast[6]. It shows that values are starting from 3132. When I open the same file in a viewer, it shows min value as 0.3132. How is that possible?

Comment: I guess there is some scaling metatag included as part of the geotiff file, like @user30184 already pointed out. So while some software products consider this, others seem to neglect the information.